# Where can I find an online function reference for LoadRunner?

Tags: reference, loadrunner

Is there an online reference manual I can query which contains details of LoadRunner functions such as:

```
lr_start_transaction
web_url
web_submit_data
web_custom_request
lr_end_transaction
```

etc.?

Essentially, I want to be able to find out about these functions without having the LoadRunner environment licenced/installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a web-based function reference but a ZIP file of Windows HTMLHelp (.CFM) files (the LoadRunner 9.10 VuGen API Reference) can be [downloaded from here](http://support.openview.hp.com/selfsolve/document/KM548035/binary/LR-version9.10-funcref.html?searchIdentifier=-294d700c%3a1212170de9d%3a14d2&resultType=document):

I found this by searching the [HP Software Product Manuals](http://support.openview.hp.com/selfsolve/manuals) with the following details (requires free registration):

```
Product: LoadRunner
Product version: 9.10 
Operating system: Windows
```

I tried version 9.50 as well but it did not provide a link...

One gotcha: once I had the .CFM on my machine I had to 'Unblock' them via the Properties dialog otherwise I got the 'This program cannot display the webpage' message within HTMLHelp.

Comment: Why do I get "access denied" for the second link?

Answer (score 1):

Every copy of LoadRunner ships with a soft copy of the manuals.

Answer (score 1):

The official reference would be at **Help** >> **Fuction Reference** in HP Loadrunner:

[image]

You can do "quick searching" by clicking on the index:

[image]

The reference is actually made up of html files (located at `HP\Loadrunner\help\function_reference\FuncRef.htm`), so they can be viewed directly in any browser.

(Btw, there are many useful gems within the `Loadrunner\help` folder too, especially the PDFs tutorials.)

Answer (score 0):

Try the search @ http://loadrunnertnt.com or ask @

[LoadRunner Group](https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?passive=true&service=groups2&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fgroups.google.com%2Fgroup%2FLR-LoadRunner%2Fsubscribe&cd=US&hl=en)